# Do function on process close?

Tags: c#, events, process, terminate

Say I have created a process using Process.Start();.

How would I tell if it had been closed/terminated, without freezing the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
Process p = Process.Start(...);
p.Exited += OnProcessExited;

private void OnProcessExited(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Put code here
}
```

There is one catch to this code though.  It's possible for the `Process` to exit before the event handler is attached.  So you may not receive this event for a `Process` which exits quickly.

Comment: One issue, it does not seem to work when you create a process, set arguments and filename, and then call PROCESSNAME.Start(); Any help?